# Where's Windows BASH?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I added the components for Windows BASH in the control panel.  It seemed to go fine, did it's download/install thing, no errors.  I rebooted.  Now, however, I don't see any way to start BASH.  Doing a search comes up empty.  I don't see any new icons in the menu.  Coming up empty with web searches too, so presumably it *should* be obvious.  Where is it supposed to show up for me to start it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash doesn't work after Windows 10 update](http://superuser.com/questions/1109788/bash-doesnt-work-after-windows-10-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command prompt window, and type in `Bash`.  This should start it up providing you have enabled the options for it in control panel (sounds like you have).

Comment: I was not in developer mode (I did not know that was still required with Anniversary edition), which it alerted me to upon running from a command prompt.  After turning on developer mode it completed the install and now appears on the menu as well.